# Symfony2 form unchecked checkbox not taken into account, why?

Tags: forms, symfony, checkbox

**When I send a form with an *unchecked* checkbox, if the related entity property equals `true`, then it does not change to `false`.**

The other way round (setting property to true when the form is sent with a checked checkbox) works fine, as well as all the forms other fields saving.

Here is how I build the form and declare the related property:

```
// --- Form creation function EntityType::buildForm() ---
$builder->add('secret', 'checkbox', array( 'required' => false ));

// --- Entity related property, Entity.php file ---
/** @ORM\Column(name="secret", type="boolean") */
protected $secret;
```

---

EDIT: *The issue happens because the form is submitted using **a PATCH request**.*

In Symfony, the `Form::submit` method is called by a Request Handler with this line:

```
$form->submit($data, 'PATCH' !== $method);
```

*As a result the `Form::submit` `$clearMissing` parameter is set to `false` in the case of a PATCH request, thus leaving the non-sent fields to their old value.*

*But I do not know how to solve the problem. If I explicitely pass a JSON `{secret: false}` to the Symfony framework when the checkbox is not checked, it will interpret it as the `"false"` string and consider that a true value, thus considering the checkbox checked...*

---

NB. I have exactly the same issue **with an array of checkboxes using a `choice` field type** (with `multiple` and `extended` to `true`) linked to a Doctrine Simple Array property: as soon as a given checkbox has been sent once as checked, it is impossible to set back the related property to `false` with subsequent `unchecked` submissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue happens because the form is submitted using **a PATCH request**.

This has lead to open [this Symfony issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/17899).

As explained, one workaround is to explicitely send a specific reserved value (for instance the string '__false') when the checkbox is unchecked (instead of sending nothing), and replace this value by 'null' using a custom data transformer in the form type:

```
// MyEntityFormType.php -- buildForm method
$builder->add('mycheckbox', ...);
$builder->get('mycheckbox')
    ->addViewTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
        function ($normalizedFormat) {
            return $normalizedFormat;
        },
        function ($submittedFormat) {
            return ( $submittedFormat === '__false' ) ? null : $submittedFormat;
        }
    ));
```

The case with the 'choice' field can't be solved the same way. It is actually a bug of Symfony, dealt with in [this issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/17799).

Comment: Sending a string of "0" technically equals false (although I did not test in this exact scenario) http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Answer (score 6):

Non of above-mentioned didn't help me. 
So, I am using this...

**Explanation**

Resolution for this issue when "PATCH" method was used, was to add additional hidden "timestamp" field inside of a form type and to have it next to the checkbox of issue in twig file. This is needed to pass something along with the checkbox, that would definitely change - time-stamp will change.

Next thing was to use PRE_SUBMIT event and to wait for form field to arrive and if it not set, I would set it manually... Works fine, and I don't mind extra code...

**FormType**

```
$builder
...
->add('some_checkbox')
->add('time_stamp', 'hidden', ['mapped' => false, 'data' => time()])
...
```

**Twig**

```
{{ form_widget(form.time_stamp) }}
{{ form_widget(form.some_checkbox) }}
```

**PRE_SUBMIT event in builder**

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) use($options) {

    $data = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();

    if (!$data) {
        return;
    }
    /* Note that PATCH method is added as an option for "createForm" 
     * method, inside of your controller 
    */       
    if ($options["method"]=="PATCH" && !isset($data['some_checkbox'])) {
        $form->getData()->setSomeCheckbox(false);//adding missing checkbox, since it didn't arrive through submit.. grrr
    }            
});
```

Comment: $form->get('someCheckbox')->setData(false) instead of $form->getData()->setSomeCheckbox(false), otherwise you still see checked checkbox after update

Comment: @VictorBredihin it worked before, so I suspect it has something to do with version of the Symfony. Which one you use? Answer should be updated to have solutions for both. This was Symfony 2.

Comment: The problem is still here in Symfony 5.3

Answer (score 2):

What version of Symfony are you using?

There should exist some code dedicated to the situation you're writing about, in `vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php`, in `Form::submit()`:

```
// Treat false as NULL to support binding false to checkboxes.
// Don't convert NULL to a string here in order to determine later
// whether an empty value has been submitted or whether no value has
// been submitted at all. This is important for processing checkboxes
// and radio buttons with empty values.
if (false === $submittedData) {
    $submittedData = null;
} elseif (is_scalar($submittedData)) {
    $submittedData = (string) $submittedData;
}
```

Located at lines 525-534 for me. Could you check this works properly for you?

Another lead would be a custom form subscriber that do not work exactly as intended - by overwriting the provided value.

Comment: I use Symfony 2.6.4 and do have these lines of code in Form.php. However, using `dump()` to visualize `$submittedData`, it shows that `$submittedData` never equals `false` in any of the `submit()` calls. If my checkbox is not checked, `submit()` is only called for other form fields but not for the checkbox. For the choice field, `submit()` is first called with an array of all the checked options `['opt1', 'opt2',etc.]`, then with each option string separately (first `'opt1'`, then `'opt2'`, etc.) but never for unchecked options and still never with a `false` value.

Comment: Staying in the same method, I recommend manual debug. The Symfony Form component can be quite tricky and it is difficult to pinpoint your problem remotely. Check that form values are modified in normal ways when exiting the PRE_SUBMIT event, check that the form parent to the checkboxes is **compound** (`$this->config->getCompound()`) and that `$child->submit()` is called.

Comment: I've found the issue (cf my own answer).  Thanks for pointing to the right way to solve the problem: manual debug ^^

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because the field isn't required on you schema. you can provide a default value to the checkbox with the following:

```
$builder->add('secret', 'checkbox', array(
  'required' => false,
  'empty_data' => false
));
```

See [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#empty-data) or [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/use_empty_data.html)

Comment: I had already tested that, but it did not work. It is worth mentionning that I send data to the form via a custom made form on the front end. I've tested explicitely sending `false` when the checkbox is not checked, but this ends up sending the `"false"` string, which is interpreted as `true` by the form.

Comment: "empty_data" is a php value used by the component it will not be converted to string, @Silverspur your try is different, this might work.

Comment: I know these are two different things. I just wanted to tell that *not only*  had I tested the use of `'empty_data'` parameter as suggested, but also the explicit sending of a `false` value :)

Comment: Actually, to be thourough, `empty_data` does not work here because when the `Form::submit` function is called with `$clearMissing` set to `false` (which is the case with a PATCH request), the fields with no data sent (among which the unchecked checkboxes) are not even considered by the submission process, so the `empty_data` value for such fields is never used.

Comment: If you are using custom code to submit the form and want to mark a checkbox as false, just leave the checkbox out of the post data. Checkbox values are only sent if checked, if not checked then the checkbox doesn't get sent at all. If you look at `CheckboxType::buildForm()` you will see that it sets the data only if a value is given, otherwise it is false. `$builder->setData(isset($options['data']) ? $options['data'] : false);`. Technically sending a string of "0" would equal false as well: http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('isActive', CheckboxType::class, array(
            'required' => false
        ))
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $e {
        $entity = $e->getData();
        $form = $e->getForm();
        $isActive = empty($_POST[$form->getName()]['isActive']) ? false : true;
        $entity->setIsActive($isActive);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to add a hidden element and make this with Javascript. It will fail in 0.1 % of the people that use a browser without javascript.
This is a simple example for a multiple checkboxes FormType element:

```
            ->add('ranges', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'label'   => 'Range',
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true,
            'choices' => array(
                null => 'None',
                'B1' => 'My range',
            )
        ))

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
       function updateDynRanges(object) {
            if (object.prop("checked")) {
                document.getElementById('ranges_0').checked = 0;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('ranges_0').checked = 1;
            }
        }
 // On page onload
        $('#ranges_1').change(function() {
           updateDynRanges($(this));
        });
        updateDynRanges($('ranges_1'));
}
</script>
```

If after testing works you can just add a visibility:false to the second checkbox.

Twig template:

```
 {{ form_label(form.dynamicRanges) }}<br>
 {{ form_widget(form.dynamicRanges[1]) }}
 <div class="hidden">{{ form_widget(form.ranges[0]) }}</div>
```

Looks like an ugly workaround, but I just wanted to compete with the other ugly suggested workarounds, in this case mostly updating the twig template.